# Infinitude of prime number of the form $x^2+14y^2$

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory

In the book "*Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$*", David Cox had shown that:
$$p=x^2+14y^2 \Longleftrightarrow (-14/p)=1 \;\text{and}\; (x^2+1)^2=8 \mod p \; \text{has an integer solution.} $$
Is this imply that there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2+14y^2$? It is easy to see that there are infinitely many primes that the equation $(x^2+1)^2=8 \mod p$ has an integer solution but I don't have any clue to check if some of them can take $-14$ as their quadratic residue.

Comment: The infinitude is an easy consequence of Cebotarev density theorem. Only knowing Dirichlet theorem (infinitude of primes in arithmetic progression) in this case is not enough.

Comment: see Theorem 9.12. In the first edition this is page 188. Every prime $p \neq 2, 7$  for which $(-56 |p)=1$   is represented by some primitive form of discriminant $-56.$   Those with $p \equiv 3,5 \pmod 8$ are represented by $ 3x^2 \pm 2xy +5 y^2.$  Those with $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod 8$ are represented by  either $ 2x^2 +7 y^2$   or $x^2 + 14 y^2,$   and each form represents exactly half the Dirichlet density of these primes.    More detail in Williams and Liu,  Tamkang Journal (1994),  Representation of Primes by the Principal Form of Negative Discriminant $\Delta$  when $h(\Delta)$ is $4$

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- I bet there is an infinity of primes and I rely for this on the following:

for instance,the four identities $$(a+3)^2+14(3b\pm2)^2=6(6a^2+6a+21b^2\pm28+11)-1\\(6a+1)^2+14(3b)^2=6(6a^2+2a+21b^2)+1\\(6a+5)^2+14(3b)^2=6(6a^2+10a+21b^2+4)+1$$ There are an infinity of values for the factors of $6$ in the three $RHS$ of the four identities which give solutions of the equation $$x^2+14y^2=6z\pm1$$ and I find very plausible suppose that there are in a lot of them primes (all prime is of the form $6z\pm1$).

Answer (score 1):

According to a theorem due to Dirichlet (proved later by various mathematicians such as A. Meyer and H. Weber), every primitive binary quadratic form represents infinitely many prime numbers.

In the case of $x^2 + 14y^2$, this follows from the observation above in addition with the fact that there are infinitely many primes that split completely in a given number field (a very special case of the standard density theorems in algebraic number theory). In your case, the number field is the Hilbert class field of $k = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-14})$ defined by the roots of $(x^2+1)^2 = 8$ over $k$.